# java.net.UnknownHostException Spring Boot AWS EC2 Apache Kafka

Tags: amazon-web-services, spring-boot, amazon-ec2, apache-kafka, spring-cloud-stream

I am running a Spring Boot app that produces messages to Kafka. When I run the app to query my local Kafka everything is ok. But once I try to query the one running on an EC2 instance I get:

```
java.net.UnknownHostException: ip-172-31-32-47.us-east-2.compute.internal
at java.base/java.net.InetAddress$CachedAddresses.get(InetAddress.java:797) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName0(InetAddress.java:1505) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1364) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1298) ~[na:na]
at org.apache.kafka.clients.ClientUtils.resolve(ClientUtils.java:110) ~[kafka-clients-2.5.0.jar:na]
at org.apache.kafka.clients.ClusterConnectionStates$NodeConnectionState.currentAddress(ClusterConnectionStates.java:403) ~[kafka-clients-2.5.0.jar:na]
at org.apache.kafka.clients.ClusterConnectionStates$NodeConnectionState.access$200(ClusterConnectionStates.java:363) ~[kafka-clients-2.5.0.jar:na]
at org.apache.kafka.clients.ClusterConnectionStates.currentAddress(ClusterConnectionStates.java:151) ~[kafka-clients-2.5.0.jar:na]
at org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient.initiateConnect(NetworkClient.java:955) ~[kafka-clients-2.5.0.jar:na]
at org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient.ready(NetworkClient.java:293) ~[kafka-clients-2.5.0.jar:na]
at org.apache.kafka.clients.admin.KafkaAdminClient$AdminClientRunnable.sendEligibleCalls(KafkaAdminClient.java:1018) ~[kafka-clients-2.5.0.jar:na]
at org.apache.kafka.clients.admin.KafkaAdminClient$AdminClientRunnable.processRequests(KafkaAdminClient.java:1260) ~[kafka-clients-2.5.0.jar:na]
at org.apache.kafka.clients.admin.KafkaAdminClient$AdminClientRunnable.run(KafkaAdminClient.java:1203) ~[kafka-clients-2.5.0.jar:na]
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834) ~[na:na]
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K5kSn.png)

Knowing that this is the app config:

```
spring.cloud.stream.kafka.binder.brokers=ec2-18-221-154-81.us-east-2.compute.amazonaws.com:9092
sending.message.timeout.ms=5000
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.output.destination=meetupTopic
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.output.producer.partitionCount=1
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.output.content-type=text/plain
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.output.producer.headerMode=none
```

and this is the producer class:

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.cloud.stream.annotation.EnableBinding;
import org.springframework.cloud.stream.messaging.Source;
import org.springframework.messaging.support.MessageBuilder;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.web.socket.WebSocketMessage;

@Component
@EnableBinding(Source.class)
public class RsvpsKafkaProducer {

    @Value("${sending.message.timeout.ms}")
    private int timeout;

    private final Source source;

    public RsvpsKafkaProducer(Source source) {
        this.source = source;
    }

    public void sendRsvpMessage(WebSocketMessage<?> message) {

        source.output().send(MessageBuilder.withPayload(message.getPayload()).build(), timeout);
    }
}
```

I tried lot of patches such as changing the region, editing the /etc/hosts file on the instance running Kafka, checking the security group, changing the OS. It's probably a Kafka problem-related to its config. Any solution or suggestion please ?

Comment: What you're showing for an address is basically the same as localhost.  Can you describe your setup a bit more?

Comment: Edit the question instead of adding code in comments; it's more readable.

Comment: https://www.confluent.io/blog/kafka-client-cannot-connect-to-broker-on-aws-on-docker-etc/

Comment: Are you able to *ping* that host from your machine?

Comment: Also editing the `/etc/hosts` should be done on the machine where your *Spring boot application is running*. Point your amazon-aws instance domain to its resolved IP, in-case there is a trouble with DNS.

Answer (score 0):

I had to add the EC2 DNS within Apache Kafka config i.e.:

```
listeners=PLAINTEXT://ec2-18-189-32-171.us-east-2.compute.amazonaws.com:9092
```

Comment: in which file did you put this?